# I need to save the DTO in the database table linked to the Entity

Tags: java, spring-mvc

I need to save the id of User and the id of Application in the database to keep track of the changes. I've tried the ModelMapper but it doesn't work and when i try to save the DTO data in the DB I've this error: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Unknown entity: it.progettogestionale.dto.generic.LogFileAppDTO

My Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "logfileapp")
public class LogFileApp implements Serializable{

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private Integer idLogApp;

@Column(name = "data")
private LocalDateTime data;
@Column(name = "nodoconsole")
private Integer nodoConsole;
@Column(name = "launchingmeetingdatagatheringstarting")
private Time launchingMeetingDataGatheringStarting;
@Column(name = "avganalysistime")
private BigDecimal avgAnalysisTime;
@Column(name = "automationenablingdate")
private Date automationEnablingDate;
@Column(name = "done")
private Boolean done;
@Column(name="idpreupdate")
private Integer idPreUpdate;
@Column
private String nome_App, apmCode, insertedInCastProgram, stakeholderEngagement,
stakeholderBrief, onBoardingKitDelivery, primaRestitution, ownerOnboarding, ownerAFP, 
gdsUnit, tecnologia, serverManager,
soloCMS, macchina, noteOnboarding, fase, afpStatus, pubblicatoDashboard, noteAppOwner,  
jiraautomationActivation,
repoAvailability, automationStatus, automationNotes, greenItIndex, 
onboardingKitClosing, sourceCodeFinalDelivery,
linkConfluence, businessCriticality, devMethodology, provider;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL , fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "FK_idUtente")
private Utente utente;

@ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL , fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumn(name = "FK_idApp")
private Applicazione applicazione;
```

My DTO

```
public class LogFileAppDTO {

private Integer idLogApp;
private LocalDateTime data;
private Integer nodoConsole;
private Time launchingMeetingDataGatheringStarting;
private BigDecimal avgAnalysisTime;
private Date automationEnablingDate;
private Boolean done;
private Integer idPreUpdate;
private String nome_App, apmCode, insertedInCastProgram, stakeholderEngagement, stakeholderBrief,
        onBoardingKitDelivery, primaRestitution, ownerOnboarding, ownerAFP, gdsUnit, tecnologia, serverManager,
        soloCMS, macchina, noteOnboarding, fase, afpStatus, pubblicatoDashboard, noteAppOwner,
        jiraautomationActivation, repoAvailability, automationStatus, automationNotes, greenItIndex,
        onboardingKitClosing, sourceCodeFinalDelivery, linkConfluence, businessCriticality, devMethodology,
        provider;
private Integer idUtente;
private Integer idApplicazione;

public LogFileAppDTO() {
}

public LogFileAppDTO(LogFileApp l) {
    super();
    idLogApp = l.getIdLogApp();
    data = l.getData();
    nodoConsole = l.getNodoConsole();
    launchingMeetingDataGatheringStarting = l.getLaunchingMeetingDataGatheringStarting();
    avgAnalysisTime = l.getAvgAnalysisTime();
    automationEnablingDate = l.getAutomationEnablingDate();
    done = l.getDone();
    idPreUpdate = l.getIdPreUpdate();
    nome_App = l.getNome_App();
    apmCode = l.getApmCode();
    insertedInCastProgram = l.getInsertedInCastProgram();
    stakeholderEngagement = l.getStakeholderEngagement();
    stakeholderBrief = l.getStakeholderBrief();
    onBoardingKitDelivery = l.getOnBoardingKitDelivery();
    primaRestitution = l.getPrimaRestitution();
    ownerOnboarding = l.getOwnerOnboarding();
    ownerAFP = l.getOwnerAFP();
    gdsUnit = l.getGdsUnit();
    tecnologia = l.getTecnologia();
    serverManager = l.getServerManager();
    soloCMS = l.getSoloCMS();
    macchina = l.getMacchina();
    noteOnboarding = l.getNoteOnboarding();
    fase = l.getFase();
    afpStatus = l.getAfpStatus();
    pubblicatoDashboard = l.getPubblicatoDashboard();
    noteAppOwner = l.getNoteAppOwner();
    jiraautomationActivation = l.getJiraautomationActivation();
    repoAvailability = l.getRepoAvailability();
    automationStatus = l.getAutomationStatus();
    automationNotes = l.getAutomationNotes();
    greenItIndex = l.getGreenItIndex();
    onboardingKitClosing = l.getOnboardingKitClosing();
    sourceCodeFinalDelivery = l.getSourceCodeFinalDelivery();
    linkConfluence = l.getLinkConfluence();
    businessCriticality = l.getBusinessCriticality();
    devMethodology = l.getDevMethodology();
    provider = l.getProvider();
    idUtente = l.getUtente().getIdUtente();
    idApplicazione = l.getApplicazione().getIdApplicazione();
}
```

I have three entities, when modifying one of them I need for my DTO the id of the modified entity and the id of the modifier user. But I can't get it into the database because my entity wants the object while the dto wants the ids.

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

For DTO <--> Entity conversion you can use:

- ModelMapper
- MapStruct
- implement the interface `Converter<S, T>` and etc.

You can't save DTO in DB beacuse it's not an Entity class.

> But I can't get it into the database because my entity wants the
> object while the dto wants the ids.
> You can change Ids to DTOs.
> Simple example:

```java
public class LogFileApp {
    private Utente utente;
}

public class LogFileAppDTO {
    private UtenteDTO utente;
}
```

If you want map nested objects with ID, so you can use deep mappings.
See this article for more information:
https://www.baeldung.com/java-modelmapper

If you want to use ModelMapper you can make work easier with additional methods. Something like:

Service:

```java
public interface MapperService {

    /**
     * Note: outClass object must have default constructor with no arguments
     *
     * @param <D>      type of result object.
     * @param <T>      type of source object to map from.
     * @param entity   entity that needs to be mapped.
     * @param outClass class of result object.
     * @return new object of <code>outClass</code> type.
     */
    <D, T> D map(T entity, Class<D> outClass);

    /**
     * Note: outClass object must have default constructor with no arguments
     *
     * @param entityList list of entities that needs to be mapped
     * @param outCLass   class of result list element
     * @param <D>        type of objects in result list
     * @param <T>        type of entity in <code>entityList</code>
     * @return list of mapped object with <code><D></code> type.
     */
    <D, T> List<D> mapAll(Collection<T> entityList, Class<D> outCLass);

    /**
     * Maps {@code source} to {@code destination}.
     *
     * @param source      object to map from
     * @param destination object to map to
     */
    <S, D> D map(S source, D destination);
}
```

Service implementation

```java
@Service
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MapperServiceImpl implements MapperService {

  private final ModelMapper modelMapper;

  /**
   * Note: outClass object must have default constructor with no arguments
   *
   * @param <D> type of result object.
   * @param <T> type of source object to map from.
   * @param entity entity that needs to be mapped.
   * @param outClass class of result object.
   * @return new object of <code>outClass</code> type.
   */
  public <D, T> D map(final T entity, Class<D> outClass) {
    return modelMapper.map(entity, outClass);
  }

  /**
   * Note: outClass object must have default constructor with no arguments
   *
   * @param entityList list of entities that needs to be mapped
   * @param outCLass class of result list element
   * @param <D> type of objects in result list
   * @param <T> type of entity in <code>entityList</code>
   * @return list of mapped object with <code><D></code> type.
   */
  public <D, T> List<D> mapAll(final Collection<T> entityList, Class<D> outCLass) {
    return entityList.stream().map(entity -> map(entity, outCLass)).collect(Collectors.toList());
  }

  /**
   * Maps {@code source} to {@code destination}.
   *
   * @param source object to map from
   * @param destination object to map to
   */
  public <S, D> D map(final S source, D destination) {
    modelMapper.map(source, destination);
    return destination;
  }
}
```